# PHP CI load .html file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi Is there a way to load .html file in a Codeigniter framework?

say example

```
public function saveimage(){
    $this->load->view("save_image_function.html");        
}
```

but it says `"unable to load requested file"` 
is there any settings I need to change?

Appreciate your help

Here is the screen shot of my code and the error

My CI code and folder
[image]

Error page

[image]

Comment: did you place the html file in views folder?

Comment: yes, it is inside the view folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI can loade html file without any extra configs, please ensure that place the html file in views's folder, and the file's name is the same as what you pass into `$this->load->view()` method.

Check this documentation and find out does there have any mistakes in your project which are violate CI's view arrangement.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

**EDIT:**

According to the screen shot you posted on, I find your `html` file's extension is `htm` not `html`, So either change file's extension to `html` or pass the right file name with the right extension into method `$this->load->view()`;

Comment: can you list the view directory and take a screenshot of that? @BrandonJakeSullano

Comment: See my edit, I think it will fix the error . @BrandonJakeSullano

Comment: Will try and get back to you

Comment: Thanks! it is error between "HTML" and "HTM" 
i did not notice that when I save html file using php designer the extension is only "htm"! good catch ( almost broke my brain)

Comment: You're welcome , if convenient please give me a votes up :)  @BrandonJakeSullano